# Unable to create user model in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

When I run the following spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  before :each do
    @user = User.new :email => "foo@bar.com", :password => "foobar", :password_confirmation => "foobar"
  end

  it "should be valid" do
    @user.should be_valid
  end
end
```

I get this error:

```
  1) User should be valid
     Failure/Error: @user = User.new :email => "foo@bar.com", :password => "foobar", :password_confirmation => "foobar"
     ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
       unknown attribute: email
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:5:in `new'
```

However, when I go in to console and run

```
user = User.new :email => "foo@bar.com", :password => "foobar", :password_confirmation => "foobar"
user.valid?
```

It returns true. For some reason, in my test, I am unable to create a User instance, saying that the email attribute is inaccessible.

Comment: BTW, you should give factory_girl a try instead of using `new` in your specs.

Answer (score 3):

Console uses the development database, but specs use the test database. Make sure `email` is defined in both.